# Silverlight validation. Problem with email validation

Tags: c#, .net, validation, silverlight-4.0

I have text box and i want to validate is valid email in textbox on button "save" click.

But standard validation have strange behaviour. When i print new email it always with error and this is wery annoing. I want to show error only after button click and then text box must become valid if got focus. Is there are standard way to do this in THE MODEL-VIEW-VIEWMODEL.

Comment: Please include some code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default behavior for changing the bound value in a `TextBox` is via `LostFocus`. You would need to change the `UpdateSourceTrigger` to be explicit.

```
<TextBox Name="MyTextBox"
         Text="{Binding Path=FirstName, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" />
```

Then in your code behind you now have to explicitly call `UpdateSource` via your `Button` click handler.

```
BindingExpression be = MyTextBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
be.UpdateSource();
```